# Having a default \tableofcontents with tocstyle package

Tags: table-of-contents, tocstyle

I am using roman numerals for everything. In my list of tables, my XVIII'th table was encroaching on the name of the table, so I did `\usepackage{tocstyle}` which completely fixed this problem.

Before I did this, my `\tableofcontents` had nice bolded `\section` names. Now that I've enabled `tocstyle`, this `\tableofcontents` has become dull. All section names in the `\tableofcontents` have the same size and lack of bolding as my `\subsection` and `\subsubsection` names.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With the current version of `tocstyle`, you should also choose a style with (e.g.) `\usetocstyle{standard}`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tocstyle}
\usetocstyle{standard}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\renewcommand*{\thesection}{\Roman{section}}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\blinddocument

\end{document}
```

[image]